# HTTP Post filters out Content-Type "text/xml"

Tags: asp.net, post, iis-7.5

My page is written in ASP.Net, and our site runs IIS 7.5.

I'm trying to receive an Xml document from an outside source posting to a page in our website. I can send a test document from a web page and receive it, using Content-Type “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”.  The sender's documents are Content-Type "text/xml."  I have modified the web.config to try various things, all of which still give us a "blank" document from the sender.  Is there some setting that I"m still missing that would cause this?

My web.config settings are:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <sessionState mode="Off" cookieless="true" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="P3P" value="policyref='https://oursite/w3c/p3p.xml',CP='NON DSP COR CUR OUR IND PUR ONL PHY'" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".aspx" mimeType="text/xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".aspx" mimeType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    </staticContent>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <httpCompression>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/xml" enabled="true"/>
      </staticTypes>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/xml" enabled="true"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: How are they posting the xml?